# javascript cloneNode and properties

Tags: javascript, properties, clonenode

Is there a quick way to "super" deep clone a node, including its properties?  (and methods, I guess)

I've got something like this:

```
var theSource = document.getElementById("someDiv")
theSource.dictator = "stalin";

var theClone = theSource.cloneNode(true);

alert(theClone.dictator);
```

The new cloned object has no `dictator` property.  Now, say I've got a thousand properties attached to `theSource` - how can I (non-explicitly) transfer/copy them to the clone?

// EDIT

@Fabrizio

Your `hasOwnProperty` answer doesn't work properly, so I adjusted it.  This is the solution I was looking for:

```
temp = obj.cloneNode(true);

for(p in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) { eval("temp."+p+"=obj."+p); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the best way to save a lot of properties is to create a property object in which you can store all properties e.g.

```
thesource.myproperties = {}
thesource.myproperties.dictator1 = "stalin"; 
thesource.myproperties.dictator2 = "ceasescu"; 
thesource.myproperties.dictator3 = "Berlusconi";
...
```

then you have to copy just one property

```
theclone.myproperties = thesource.myproperties
```

otherwise do a `for` cycle for all properties you have stored

```
for (p in thesource) {
  if (thesource.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    theclone.p = thesource.p;
  }
}
```